# Element disappears when animating relative wrapper width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a strange problem that happens when I animate the `width` of a `relative` positioned element which contains an `absolute` element. While the animation is running, inner element dissapears. When the animation is complete, inner element shows.

Here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Cj5/

When I remove parent element `position: relative` then inner element is shown while animation is running, but then I can't position it relatively to the parent.

> Basically  box with the % should be visible al the time

Does anyone have any idea whats happening here?

> FIXED : I just added overflow: visible !important; to relative
>   positioned element

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/R4Cj5/26/

Comment: what you exactly want. can you please explain more. because you showed fiddle works fine.

Comment: @pathaktejpal  Look at the little box with the % above the bar, while the bar is animating it is not shown (but it should be), as the animation finishes, it immediately shows
It sahould be visible all the time

Comment: Make overflow : hidden to relative parent element and check it once.

Comment: @redv than its not visible at all

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a jQuery animate thing.  I would love to see a working solution without any hacks, but for now here is [something you might find useful](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/R4Cj5/25/)! :-)

I basically added another function in the animate, upon completion it will animate the 90% to hover above the progress-bar

```
complete: function() {
    $percent.animate({top: "-26px"})
}
```

in this use-case scenario, you can also **remove/comment** out the `top: -26px` from `.progressbar .percent` in the stylesheet.  Also I added `height: 20px;` to the styling for `.progressbar .percentage` so you could see the % change as it glides across.